# Docker service : Configure 2 different services should never come on same VM

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have scaleset (in Azure) with 3 VMs (all VMs have same label). Am deploying all containers via docker swarm.

I want 2 services never to be deployed on same VM.

In constraint can we define this?

Answer (score 0):

[Container Distribution](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/infrastructure/deployment-strategies/) can help you here. 
There are options for high availability.

Comment: page is no more present